# Primefaces - at least one field required with one message for all fields

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to perform primefaces validation to validate that one field in the form has to be filled in? When none are filled in, all fields have to be marked red (happens automatically) and only one message may be displayed in the messages tag. Right now a message is displayed for each required field and I don't want that.

I've tried:

```
<p:messages id="messages" redisplay="false"/>
```

but this doesn't filter them.

An example of one of the many inputFields:

```
        <p:inputText id="from" value="#{containerBean.selectedContainer.from}"
                     maxlength="512"
                     requiredMessage="#{msgs['one.field.required']}"
                     required="#{empty param['containerForm:description']
                         and empty param['containerForm:to']
                         and empty param['containerForm:year']
                         and empty param['containerForm:yearTo']
                         and empty param['containerForm:sequence']}"
                     disabled="#{documentBean.addNewOrUpdateDocumentSelected or !containerBean.canEditSelectedContainer()}"/>
```

I know it's possible with omnifaces, but I may not use it :)..

PF 5.3

I also know that I could perform the validation in my BackingBean, but that's not a good practice..

Comment: Are you using OmniFaces or open to? The <o:validateOneOrMore> does exactly what you want.

Comment: @BalusC just made a modification. I may not use it.

Comment: You could do it in a bean level.

Comment: I won't say that backend validaton is not good practice. The fact that you have a long condition in your "required" is not good practice. As a rule of thumb, we try to minimize the logic in the XHTML. 

As PF doesn't have a component like  <o:validateOneOrMore>. I guess that's the only option you have. unless you try to eliminate redundant error messages in the facescontext.

Comment: @ShadyAziz that last thing is what I would love to achieve on some way

Comment: As I said, in PF according to my knowledge, there is no way to acheive this in the XHTML. You must do it in your controller/validator.